# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message

Tags: php, mongodb

I am testing the mongoDB in localhost and successfully installed the mongoDB in localhost. I have tried to connect the mongoDB using PHP in localhost.

It throws the error like 'Authentication failed'. It is successfully authenticated in cmd prompt.

### Below is my code:

$username = 'testUser';

$password = 'testPassword';

$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://testUser:testPassword@localhost", array("db" => "testdb"));

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ' in E:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\test.php:3 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\test.php(3): MongoClient->__construct('localhost:27017', Array) #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\test.php on line 3

I have also changed the localhost to ip(127.0.0.1) address but no use. Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably the mongo server is not listening in the correct port, or you have a firewall blocking the request

Comment: Thanks for your reply..When i connect through Mongochef it's authenticated correctly..When i manually connect through Monogclient it not connected or how we set the listening port for mongodb...

Comment: I have same question, please answer someone who knows..